# Sort object by property is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I followed the documentation about `sort` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example. It's not working. I even get a weirder issue: after hours, I discovered that if I change `var comparator` to `function comparator(a,b)`, it works. Why is that??

```
test();

var comparator = (a, b) => {
    if (a.min !== b.min) {
        if (a.min < b.min) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return +1
        }
    } else {
        if (a.max !== b.max) {
            if (a.max < b.max) {
                return -1
            } else {
                return +1
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
function test() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        var tests = [{min: 18, max: 20},
            {min: 17, max: 20},
            {min: 10, max: 11}];
        console.log(tests.sort(comparator), 'test sorted');
    }

}
```

Comment: read up on variable hoisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of variable [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) issue. You are trying to call a function expression before it is defined. When you run it `comparator` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the call of the function`test` at the end, it will work. This is relevant to *[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)* in JavaScript.

```js
var comparator = (a, b) => {
    if (a.min !== b.min) {
        if (a.min < b.min) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return +1
        }
    } else {
        if (a.max !== b.max) {
            if (a.max < b.max) {
                return -1
            } else {
                return +1
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

function test() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        var tests = [{min: 18, max: 20},
            {min: 17, max: 20},
            {min: 10, max: 11}];
        console.log(tests.sort(comparator), 'test sorted');
    }

}

test();
```

**Update**

As charlietfl has pointed out in his comment due to hoisting your script would also work, if you move the call of the `test` function right after the `comparator` declaration.

```js
var comparator = (a, b) => {
    if (a.min !== b.min) {
        if (a.min < b.min) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return +1
        }
    } else {
        if (a.max !== b.max) {
            if (a.max < b.max) {
                return -1
            } else {
                return +1
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

test();

function test() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        var tests = [{min: 18, max: 20},
            {min: 17, max: 20},
            {min: 10, max: 11}];
        console.log(tests.sort(comparator), 'test sorted');
    }

}
```

Comment: can also place it before the function declaration since that will be hoisted

Comment: @charlietfl correct ! Thanks for pointing this also. I just updated my answer.